# What mean <K,V> before HashMap<K,V>? Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

I'm reading the book Effective programming in Java and during the reading I met such a code snippet:

```
public static <К, V> HashMap<K, V> newInstance() {
    return new HashMap<K, V>();
}
```

what does the expression `<K, V>` between static and `HashMap<K,V>` how it is called and works? I've heard about generics, but I do not know them well and I want to know why it's impossible to write some like:

```
public static HashMap<K, V> newInstance() {
    return new HashMap<K, V>();
}
```

why before `HashMap<K, V>` I need to write `<К, V>`?

Comment: `Map`s contain **K**ey **V**alue *pairs*. `K` is the type of the **key**. `V` is the type of the **value**. Without the generic type `<K, V>` it would be a raw-type, that is `Object` key and `Object` value.

Comment: btw this is called a *generic method*

Comment: the fist `<K,V>` is called "introducing" the generic type. If you omit it, the function does not know what K and V are

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
public static HashMap<K, V> newInstance() {
    return new HashMap<K, V>();
}
```

`K` and `V` are regular identifiers that must be resolved to some type (class name or interface name).

For example, if you wanted a method that returns a `HashMap` having a `String` key and `Integer` value, you could write:

```
public static HashMap<String,Integer> newInstance() {
    return new HashMap<String,Integer>();
}
```

This method will always return a `HashMap<String,Integer>`, so you can only assign it to:

```
HashMap<String,Integer> map = newInstance();
```

However, if you want `K` and `V` to be generic type parameters, you must declare them as such. That's what you do with `<K,V>`:

```
public static <К, V> HashMap<K, V> newInstance() {
    return new HashMap<K, V>();
}
```

This allows you to use this method to return `HashMap`s of different key and value types:

```
HashMap<String,Integer> map1 = newInstance();
HashMap<Long,Boolean> map2 = newInstance();
...
```